# Discount Sale GUI

Tags: java

I'm encountering problems with my discount sale program. This program is supposed to prompt the user for the amount of purchases and then returns the discounted price. The discounted price is 10% and is only taken off purchases over 10$. So, the problem im encounting is everytime I put in 20$ and press submit, it gives me "null" and "null" for the other two fields. when it should display the discount amount and the total.

What needs to be changed with the part of the code that sais "=null"?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat ("$#,##0.00");
    double purchases, discount, finalPrice;
    purchases = Double.parseDouble (PurchaseAmountTxt.getText ());

    if (purchases >= 10) {
        discount = purchases * 0.10;
    } else { 
        discount = 0;
    }
    finalPrice = purchases - discount;
    Object Discount = null;

    DiscountTxt.setText(String.valueOf(Discount));
    Object FinalPrice = null;

    DiscountPriceTxt.setText(String.valueOf(FinalPrice));
}
```

Comment: `Object FinalPrice = null`?

Comment: yeah. for some reason it said I hadnt initialized the final price or discount variable so it fixed it by putting null ?? That was my only error in my code that it showed me.

Answer (score 1):

You never assign a value to either `Discount` or `FinalPrice`, they are both `null`

```
Object Discount = null;

DiscountTxt.setText(String.valueOf(Discount));
Object FinalPrice = null;

DiscountPriceTxt.setText(String.valueOf(FinalPrice));
```

You can just do away with those objects altogether and use the values you already have

```
System.out.println("discount = " + x.format(discount));
System.out.println("FinalPrice = " + x.format(finalPrice));
```

Which in my testing print out

```
discount = $2.00
FinalPrice = $18.00
```